# Python: Reordering a list with many entries

Tags: python

I have a list in python with 10,000+ temperature entries without their corresponding dates. In essence, the first 12 entries are October 1st, November 1st , ... September 1st. The following 12 entries are October 2nd, November 2nd, ... September 2nd. This continues all the way until the 31st day.

This scheme also repeats for 20 years (i.e. 1980 to 2000)

Instead, I want to organize these values in a more sensible format ... October 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.

Is there an easy way about doing this? I've tried for loops but to no avail. I am pretty new to coding, so the simpler the better.

```
###Code to getting the list:###
rawdata = open('')
data = csv.reader(rawdata)
listoflists = []
for i in e1:
    listoflists.append(i)
    print(i)

temperaturelist = []

for sublist in listoflists:
    for item in sublist:
        temperaturelist.append(item)

for i in temperaturelist:
    if i < 13:
        newlist = ...
```

Sorry this is probably a large problem with multiple issues rather than a more optimal way to code "x".

Comment: What is `e1` on line 5

Comment: sorry e1 should be "data." I tried to clean up my code before I posted it here.

Comment: Are there entries for the 31st of months that don't have have a 31st day?

Comment: And for February, which will vary between 28 and 29 days depending on the year.

Comment: yes, for entries like February 31st, the entry is "----" and the same for any invalid day. I could delete these days pretty easily, I think.

Comment: No, leave them. Those make the task *much* easier.

Comment: Are the first 12 entries on the same first row, and the next 12 entries on the same second row, etc.?

Comment: Each value is on its own "index" or row. I have 10000 values, and therefore the length of the list is 10000. If that was what you were asking? I can make it so there are 12 items on a row, so that there are 10,000 / 12 indexes.

Comment: by doing october = [] then october.append(temperaturelist[::12] I can get the correct values for october for all 20 years. I did the same process for each month, but I made the index [1::12] for November, etc. Now I need to splice them together every 31 values each to construct each year.

Answer (score 0):

Do you notice the European way to print "October 2, 1980" is "2/10/1980"? And the order of dates you mention is just the lexicographic ordering of such dates.

If that is the case, you can try the following:

First generate all dates (you have to make sure your data is exactly all these days, no more and no less):

```
import datetime
d0 = datetime.date(1980, 1, 1)
dN = datetime.date(2000, 12, 31)
delta = datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

dates = []
printdates = []
d = d0
while d <= dN:
    dates.append(d)
    printdates.append("{d.day}/{d.month}/{d.year}".format(d=d))
    d = d + delta
```

Then sort them in lexicographic order, using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
date_df = pd.DataFrame({'print_date': printdates,
                        'date': dates}
                      ).sort_values("print_date")
```

Now goes to your CSV data. Load them using pandas, assign the date columns, then sort by the real date:

```
csv_df = pd.read_csv(...)
csv_df["print_date"] = date_df["print_date"]
csv_df["date"] = date_df["date"]
csv_df = csv_df.sort_values("date")
```

I didn't test these code. There might be bugs. But I wish you get the concept.

Comment: I think I follow your code, but the CSV doesnt contain dates in itself. If I attempt to implement your code, I get a key error "not in index" consisting of all my dates. Therefore, I dont think it can sort the data if there's no data column in the csv. Or am I missing something?

Comment: date column is added by the line `df["date"] = dates["date"]`. Your csv gives `df` and the `dates` is generated by the for-loop. The idea is, I know the order of csv is according to the `print_date` column, and afterwards, I want to sort by the `date` column.

Comment: oh okay I get it. Do you know anything about resolving that error? KeyError: "Not in index" (for all dates)?  Thanks for the help

Comment: I really mean `print_date`. The plural ones are Python lists and the singular ones are pandas DataFrame column names. (I used `dates` in different places, now fixed) I don't know how or which line you get the KeyError, sorry.

Comment: My bad, I fixed my error. The result is almost what I need, but is there a way to flatten the csv_df? Currently there's 900+ rows of 14, while I need 10000 rows of 1. I think the date was "appending" itself correctly, but without a flat list, it'll only "append" 6 years or so.

Comment: Concat columns: `pd.concat([df["col1"], df["col2"], ...])`. Or in your case, I guess, this will work: `pd.concat([df[x] for x in df.columns])`

Comment: This worked, except the values and the dates dont line up correctly. The dates are 10/1, 10/2, 10/3, etc; however, the values they represent are still 10/1, 11/1. 12/1, etc.

Comment: I modified the code. My original posting was wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work well with my project. Thanks for explaining the code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, from the original list...

- for the first year, values for...

  - the first month should be at indexes [0, 12, 24, ..., 360]
  - the second month should be at indexes [1, 13, 25, ..., 361]
  - ...
  - the last month should be at indexes [11, 23, 35, ..., 371]
- for the second year, values for...

  - the first month should be at indexes [372, 384, 396, ..., 732]
  - ...

You could first make a utility iterator which returns sublists of configurable sizes:

```
def iter_by(length, some_iterable):
    iterator = iter(some_iterable)
    while True:
        dozen = [next(iterator) for _ in range(length)]
        yield dozen
```

using it, you could esealy retrieve lists of same day of month:

```
plenty_of_values = range(20 * 12 * 31)  # 20 years, 12 months, 31 days 
same_month_day_list = list(iter_by(12, plenty_of_values))
# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
#  [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
#  [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
#  etc...]
```

This is equivalent to:

- first year, first day of months
- first year, second day of months
- ...
- first year, 31th day of months
- second year, first fay of months
- ...

Then you can zip those lists by chunks of 31 to get lists of consecutives days for each consecutive month for each consecutive years:

```
ordered_years = [list(zip(*year)) for year in iter_by(31, ame_month_day_list)]
# [[(0, 12, 24, 36, ..., 360),
#   (1, 13, 25, 37, ..., 361),
#   (2, 14, 26, 38, ..., 362),
#   (3, 15, 27, 39, ..., 363),
#   (4, 16, 28, 40, ..., 364),
#   (5, 17, 29, 41, ..., 365),
#   (6, 18, 30, 42, ..., 366),
#   (7, 19, 31, 43, ..., 367),
#   (8, 20, 32, 44, ..., 368),
#   (9, 21, 33, 45, ..., 369),
#   (10, 22, 34, 46, ..., 370),
#   (11, 23, 35, 47, ..., 371)],
#  [(372, 384, ..., 732),
#   (373, 385, ..., 733),
#   ...
#   (383, 395, ..., 743)],
#  [(744, 756, ..., 1104),
#   (745, 757, ..., 1105),
#   ...
#   (755, 767, ..., 1115)],
#   etc...
# ]
```

The result is a list which contains a list for each year.
Each year list contains a tuple for each month.
Each month contains values for each day.
The whole think is ordered temporaily.